# Roadmap to the Carleson-Hunt theorem

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series

I've recently started to learn about Fourier series from Grafakos' Classical Fourier Analysis, and I just stumbled upon the Carleson-Hunt theorem. Besides being my new favorite theorem, I'd really like to understand the proof laid out in Chapter 6 of Grafakos' Modern Fourier Analysis.

Can anyone recommend a better (i.e. more concise) reading path than just reading everything in Grafakos' two books? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I think this question is answered https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12126/accessible-proof-of-carlesons-l2-theorem?rq=1